How to add item to List with MVVM Pattern in WPF
How can i update my TerminalList-View with the current Terminals in the MVVM-Pattern in WPF? I pass the List _terminals to the ViewModel but i dont know how to assign it to the observable collection? The Code is from the Tutorial of SingletonSean
My App.xaml.cs
namespace TerminalKonfigurator
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for App.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        private readonly List<Terminal> _terminals;
        private readonly NavigationStore _navigationStore;
        public App()
        {
            Terminal terminal1 = new Terminal("Terminal1", "129,22,22,31");
            Terminal terminal2 = new Terminal("Terminal2", "129,22,22,32");
            _navigationStore = new NavigationStore();

            _terminals = new List<Terminal>();
            _terminals.Add(terminal1);
            _terminals.Add(terminal2);
        }

        private AddTerminalViewModel createAddTerminalViewModel()
        {
            return new AddTerminalViewModel(_terminals, new Services.NavigationService(_navigationStore, createTerminalListViewModel));
        }

        private TerminalListViewModel createTerminalListViewModel()
        {
            return new TerminalListViewModel(_terminals, new Services.NavigationService(_navigationStore, createAddTerminalViewModel));
        }

        protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
        {
            _navigationStore.CurrentViewModel = createTerminalListViewModel();

            MainWindow = new MainWindow()
            {
                DataContext = new MainViewModel(_navigationStore)
            };
            MainWindow.Show();

            base.OnStartup(e);
        }
    }
}

My TerminalListViewModel
namespace EMC.TerminalKonfigurator.ViewModels
{
    public class TerminalListViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        List<Terminal> terminals = new List<Terminal>();
        private readonly ObservableCollection<TerminalViewModel> _terminals;
        public IEnumerable<TerminalViewModel> Terminals => _terminals;
        public ICommand NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand { get; }

        public TerminalListViewModel(List<Terminal> terminals, Services.NavigationService addTerminalNavigationService) 
        {
            _terminals = new ObservableCollection<TerminalViewModel>();
            NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand = new NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand(addTerminalNavigationService);

            UpdateTerminals();
        }

        **private void UpdateTerminals()
        {
        }**
    }
}

My TerminalListView:
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="Terminal Liste" HorizontalAlignment="Left"></TextBlock>
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Command="{Binding NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand}" Content="add" HorizontalAlignment="Right"></Button>
    </Grid>
    <ListView Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Terminals, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Terminalname">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding terminalName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="IP-Adresse">
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding ip, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Center"></TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</Grid>

Thanks!

Please read Data Binding Overview. There should be a public Terminals property in the current view model, i.e. the DataContext of TerminalListView. That property would typically be a readonly collection, like public ObservableCollection<TerminalViewModel> Terminals { get; } = new(); Besides that, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged on all the Bindings is pointless and should be removed. It has nothing to do with the PropertyChanged event and does not affect OneWay Bindings.

The "logical" place to (async) load and bind to a collection is in the constructor or Loaded event of the target Window or Page; not in the App's "mainline". One starts with an observable collection; loads one an item at a time; or uses an existing "list" in the constructor. One then "updates" the observable collection going forward; in the "target" Page / Window; using "code that is not code-behind".

If you're going to follow MVVM pattern, you should first consider, who is changing the data? is it a user input (does the user add a terminal so the view would be updated subsequently?), if so, you should make the observableCollection public and add to the collection directly. it will update the view automatically. You won't need something like UpdateTerminals method.
public class TerminalListViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<TerminalViewModel> Terminals { get; }
    public ICommand NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand { get; }

    public TerminalListViewModel(List<Terminal> terminals, Services.NavigationService addTerminalNavigationService) 
    {
        // the assignment below assumes that the TerminalViewModel
        // class has a constructor that accepts a Terminal argument

        Terminals = new(terminals.Select(t => new TerminalViewModel(t)));

        NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand = new NavigateAddTerminalViewCommand(addTerminalNavigationService);
    }
}

Any event that causes a terminal to be added to the collection should call viewmodel, and the viewmodel should be responsible to add new items ViewModel.Terminals.Add(new TerminalViewModel()) or maybe through a Command. and then viewmodel could update anything that should be updated (like calling a service to update the database or api).
You could keep the constructor in viewmodel class to initialize the ObservableCollection.

How would Terminals = new(terminals); work with List<Terminal> terminals? The same for ViewModel.Terminals.Add(new Terminal()).

Having non-synchronized terminals and Terminals doesn't make sense. Just remove terminals field. If you want to have Terminals public setter (to set a whole new collection from other VM?), then it needs to be a full property with notification.

Having an ObservableCollection in your viewmodel indicates that you want the view to be aware of the changes in the collection of terminals. First when you are creating the VM instance, You could add all the items at once. nothing needs to be notified. But once the VM is created, you need to add each Item at a time. if you look at events supported by ObservableCollection they are only simple Crud operations, it does not understand the whole collection being changed.

If you want to synchronized the terminals collection in the model, you should do it through the VM. not the other way around. Imagine you're getting your data from a database or an restful api. first you get all the data, before your view is created. so you could create the ObservableCollection with the List<Terminal> terminals. as user interact with terminal (remove one thing or add another), you have to both update your view and update the model (api or database)

this could be done in many ways. but the simplest approach is to change the observable by using Add or Remove methods. and subscribe to CollectionChanged event of the observable in order to update the model (to synchronize the model). I highly recommend you study both INotifyPropertyChange and INotifyCollectionChange interfaces if you haven't already. It would be a hard task to manage these if you have a poor understanding of the subject.

Do you understand that you can not directly initialize an ObservableCollection<A> from a List<B>?

As far as I understood your code, you don't have Model and ViewModel for Terminal (what do you mean by A and B?), So yes You can initialize ObservableCollection<Terminal> using any IEnumerable<Terminal>. there for List<Terminal> could be used to initialize using the constructor. ObservableCollection<Terminal> collection = new ObservableCollection<Terminal>(terminal)

@NimaGhomri It is not my code. Someone writing a comment is not necessarily the person who asked the question. When you try to compile Terminals = new(terminals); or ViewModel.Terminals.Add(new Terminal()), you get a compiler error. Try it out, then you may perhaps realize what I mean with A and B.

@Clemens go check out this constructor, you will perhaps realize that ObservableCollections could be initialized using IEunmerables. I'm not going to explain new() keyword syntax.

@NimaGhomri But not when the collections contain elements of different type. As already said, you can not construct an ObservableCollection<ClassA> from an IEnumerable<ClassB>. No idea what else to say if you still don't get it. Use your compiler.

I have edited your post so that the code compiles.

@Clemens You're absolutely correct, my bad. I didn't aware of TerminalViewModel. I thought there is only one class Terminal, as I've falsely stated that "you don't have Model and ViewModel for Terminal".
